# Dynamically added properties do always return value of latest member processed in __init__

Tags: python, properties, ironpython

## Goal

I am trying to write a generic wrapper to expose members of Python objects to make them properties so they can be used for databinding in WPF in an IronPython form.
Since the IronPython script is running inside a .NET application I do not have direct access to the mdefinition of the objects, only through the IronPython scripting interface exposing them.

Since there are a lot of objects I want to expose like this with a very different hierarchy and structure I would like to make my wrapper as generic as possible over writing a specific wrapper for every object.

## Implementation

```py
class MyObservable(object):

    def __get(self, member):
        print('Getting member %s' % member) # DEBUG
        v = getattr(self.__object, member)
        print('Value: ', v) # DEBUG
        return v
        
    def __init__(self, t):

        self.__object = t
        
        # Filter out private members
        members = filter(lambda member: not(member.startswith('__')), dir(self.__object))
        
        # Filter callable methods
        try:
            members = filter(lambda member: callable(getattr(self.__object, member)), members)
        except SystemError:
            # Ignore SystemError: Object has no member '__call__' exceptions on ScriptObject members
            pass

        for member in members:
            v = self.__get(member) # DEBUG
            print(member, v) # DEBUG
            setattr(MyObservable, member, property(lambda self: v))
```

## Test case (über simplified)

Below is a very simplified test case demonstrating my problem with the simplest mock-up of a python object to be exposed:

```py
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def Test1(self):
...         return 1
...     def Test2(self):
...         return 2
>>> test=MyObservable(Foo())
Getting member Test1
Value:  <bound method Foo.Test1 of <Foo object at 0x00000000000002EF>>
Test1 <bound method Foo.Test1 of <Foo object at 0x00000000000002EF>>
Getting member Test2
Value:  <bound method Foo.Test2 of <Foo object at 0x00000000000002EF>>
Test2 <bound method Foo.Test2 of <Foo object at 0x00000000000002EF>>
```

## Problem

Creating the properties works as expected as they do all exist and seem to be iterated over properly. Although the second instance seems to reference the same object as the first, despite the fact it states that it is trying to get the correct member.

```py
>>> dir(test)
['Test1', 'Test2', '_MyObservable__get', '_MyObservable__object', '_MyObservable__set', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
>>>
```

However when I try to access their values I always get the value returned from the last member set during `__init__()`. With above sample I get output below:

```py
>>> test.Test1
<bound method Foo.Test2 of <Foo object at 0x00000000000002EF>>
>>> test.Test1()
2
>>> test.Test2
<bound method Foo.Test2 of <Foo object at 0x00000000000002EF>>
>>> test.Test2()
2
>>>
```

Apparently assignment in `__init__()` does not work as intended as it seems to assign the same reference for every member.

Anyone able to spot my mistake?
Suggestions for a different and working approach keeping in mind the intended goal?

Comment: This is related to the fact that your lambda variable `v` is not tied to the call of the lambda, it's akin to a global variable. Try `f = [lambda: x for x in range(3)]; f[0]()`. What should the return be? You'd probably expect `0`, but it returns `2`

Comment: Thanks, that is another example, but unfortunately it does not bring me closer to a solution :-(. Hopefully someone else will chime in.

Comment: It's the key as to why you are seeing both `Test1` and `Test2` being bound to `Test2`. You have bound `test.<method>` to a lambda that looks like `lambda self: some_global`. `some_global` updates from `Test1` to `Test2`, hence your issue. How to get around it? Not totally sure